# Structured message compression

Tags: compression, protocol-buffers

Are there any libraries for compression of structured messages?  (like protobufs)

I am looking for something better than just passing a serialized stream through GZip.  For example, if my message stores a triangle mesh, the coordinates of adjacent vertices will be highly correlated, so a smart compressor could store deltas instead of the raw coordinates, which would require less bits to encode.
Whereas a general compressor, that doesn't know anything about the stream structure, would be looking for repeating byte sequences, which in data like that, there won't be many.

Ideally, this should work completely automatically after being provided with a schema, but I wouldn't mind adding annotations to my schema, if it came to that.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that most of the time writing some schema will have a similar effort to programming a preprocessor for the data yourself. E.g. for your triangle mesh example, reordering the data or doing a delta on coordinates can be implemented very easy and will support any subsequent compressor very well.

A compressor going in that direction is [ZPAQ](http://www.mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html). It can use config files tailored to specific data (the [sample configuration site](http://www.mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaqutil.html) includes EXE, JPG, BMP configs as well as a specialized one to compress a file containing the mathematical constant pi). The downside is that the script language used here (ZPAQL) is quite complicated to use and you've got to know much of the ZPAQ internals.

Older versions of WinRAR used a virtual machine named RarVM (though deprecated now) that allowed for assembler-like code for custom data transformations, there's an [open source project named rarvmtools](https://github.com/taviso/rarvmtools) on GitHub with some related tools.

For protobuf compression, there's a [Google project called riegeli](https://github.com/google/riegeli) that might be able to further compress them.

Comment: In this case I already have data in protobuf format for other reasons.  But now I need to transmit it over a limited bandwidth channel.  I can roll a hand-written encoder, as you suggest, but then I'd have to keep it in sync with protobuf schema.

I was hoping to find a protobuf schema-driven compression filter, which would be more automated.  Riegeli looks potentially interesting, however, it is not clear if it would do delta-transform on

Comment: ... repeated floats, or would it just pass serialized messages through a general-purpose compressor?   Also, its main focus seems to be on providing random access and data integrity.